# ¿Cómo podría mostrar los valores de una tabla partiendo de una id primaria?

Tags: php, mysqli

Lo que pretendo es:

Demos por un caso que tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
|  id  |  lux  |
|------|-------|
|   1  |  22.5 |
|   2  |  23.5 |
|   3  |  25.5 |
|   4  |  27.5 |
|   5  |  23.5 |
|   6  |  24.5 |
|   7  |  24.5 |
|   8  |  22.5 |
|   9  |  29.5 |
|  10  |  21.5 |
```

Pues lo que pretendo es que desde el cliente envíe el valor de la **`id`** más la **cantidad de valores a mostrar a partir de esa `id`**, me explico con un ejemplo mejor:

Demos por hecho que nos llega del cliente la id con un **valor de 4** y una **cantidad de 5**, pues pretendo que **se devuelvan los siguientes 5 valores a la id dada**, lo cual el servidor me debería devolver lo siguiente:

```
|   4  |  27.5 |
|   5  |  23.5 |
|   6  |  24.5 |
|   7  |  24.5 |
|   8  |  22.5 |
```

El código que tengo hasta ahora con **PHP** es el siguiente:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$db = "meteo";

$quantity = intval($_POST["quantity"]); //Este sería el valor de la id
$current = intval($_POST["current"]); //Este sería el valor de la cantidad

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} else {

    $sql = "SELECT temp1, temp2, lux, date FROM records";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);


    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

        $i = $current;
        $param = array();

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            if ($i >= $current+$quantity) {
                break;
            }

            $param[$i] = array($row["temp1"],$row["temp2"],$row["lux"], $row["date"]);
            $i++;
        }

        echo json_encode($param);

    } else {
        echo null;
    } 
}
```

Como se puede apreciar ya he intentado hacer lo que pretendía, pero claro, me di cuneta de que cuando en el cliente consultaba, por ejemplo, **100 nuevos valores me devolvía otra vez los mismos**, cuando en realidad deberían ser los **100 valores siguientes a la `id` dada por el cliente**.

Agradecería cualquier ayuda posible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes probar con la siguiente query

```
"SELECT temp1, temp2, lux, date FROM records WHERE id > ".$id_parametro." LIMIT ".$valor_limite.";
```

Comment: No podré probarlo hasta mañana, pero da la impresión de que si va a funcionar ;). De antemano muchas gracias por tu rápida respuesta.

Comment: oka @Javi cualquier consulta sobre mi respuesta me avisas!

Comment: Gracias! No sabía que se pudiera hacer eso :)